# Add a row for each unique column value only if it doesn't already exist

Tags: sql, postgresql, exists, postgresql-10

I have two tables: `IsCompanyValid` and `CompanyData`.

`IsCompanyValid`:

```
Company   IsValid
A         TRUE
B         TRUE
C         TRUE
D         FALSE
```

`CompanyData`:

```
Company   Data
A         Data1
A         Data1
A         Data1
B         Data1
B         Data1
C         Data1
D         Data1
```

I want to insert Data called 'testData' into `CompanyData`, for each unique company that is valid. So I want the `CompanyData` to look like this:

`CompanyData`:

```
Company   Data
A         Data1
A         Data1
A         Data1
B         Data1
B         Data1
C         Data1
D         Data1
A         testData
B         testData
C         testData
```

Here is the query I wrote:

```
INSERT into CompanyData (Company, Data)
SELECT
    distinct Company,
    'testData'
FROM CompanyData

-- Make sure the data we are inserting is for valid companies only
WHERE Company in
(
    select Company from IsCompanyValid
    where IsValid = true
)
AND 'testData' not in
(
    select Data from CompanyData
);
```

Now this works fine. But if the `CompanyData` table was slightly modified, so that 'testData' already exists, this query will no longer work. For example:

`CompanyData`:

```
Company   Data
A         Data1
A         Data1
A         Data1
B         Data1
B         Data1
C         Data1
D         Data1
A         testData
```

This query will no longer insert for B and C. I'm not sure how I can modify my query to insert for B and C.
The real data is much larger, so I need to make my solution generalized.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This inserts row like requested:

```sql
INSERT INTO CompanyData(Company, Data)
SELECT i.Company, 'testData'::text
FROM   IsCompanyValid i
WHERE  i.IsValid 
AND    NOT EXISTS (
   SELECT FROM CompanyData d
   WHERE  d.Company = i.Company
   AND    d.Data = 'testData'
   );
```

Companies are skipped where a row with `Data = 'testData'` already exists.

Should also be *fast* and NULL-safe (as opposed to `NOT IN`) with an index on `CompanyData(Company, Data)`.
Or even faster with a more specialized partial index:

```
CREATE INDEX foo ON CompanyData(Company)
WHERE  Data = 'testData';
```

But the special index only pays if you keep needing it.

See:

- [Select rows which are not present in other table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19363481/select-rows-which-are-not-present-in-other-table/19364694#19364694)

Aside: consider legal, lower-case, unquoted identifiers in Postgres. See:

- [Are PostgreSQL column names case-sensitive?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20878932/are-postgresql-column-names-case-sensitive/20880247#20880247)

Comment: Thanks for pointing me in the right direction Erwin! And thanks for your other advice as well!